Use ramda to create nested object array from previous object array
I have Data like this:
[{fooId: '1', prop:'bla',prop2: 'bla', barId:'1', prop_1: 'bla', prop2_1: 'bla' },
{fooId: '1', prop:'bla',prop2: 'bla', barId:'2', prop_1: 'bla', prop2_1: 'bla' },
{fooId: '2', prop:'bla',prop2: 'bla', barId:'3', prop_1: 'bla', prop2_1: 'bla' },
{fooId: '2', prop:'bla',prop2: 'bla', barId:'4', prop_1: 'bla', prop2_1: 'bla' }]

and need to transform it like this using ramda:
[{fooId: '1', prop:'bla',prop2: 'bla', bars:[
{barId:'1', prop: 'bla', prop2: 'bla'},
{barId:'2', prop: 'bla', prop2: 'bla'}] },
{fooId: '2', prop:'bla',prop2: 'bla', bars:[
{barId:'3', prop: 'bla', prop2: 'bla'},
{barId:'4', prop: 'bla', prop2: 'bla'}] }
]

I used R.pick() to get a data structure like this however I got a new requirement and now properties need to be renamed. Using this reducer function I've got all Bars in every Foo instead of just the corresponding ones.
const transformQueryResult = r.pipe(
    r.groupBy(
        r.prop('fooId')
    ),
    r.map(r.reduce((enrichedFoo, fooWithBar) =>{
       enrichedFoo.fooId = fooWithBars.barId
       enrichedFoo.prop1 = fooWithBars.prop1
       enrichedFoo.prop2 = fooWithBars.prop2
       enrichedFoo.bars = r.append(
           {barId: fooWithBars.barId,
            prop1:fooWithBars.prop1_1,
            prop2:fooWithBars.prop2_1
           }, enrichedFoo.bars || []
      );
      return enrichedFoo;
    },{} )
),
r.values
)


Thanks in advance for every bit of help. I am new to functional programming and could solve this using loops in a minute but I am really struggling here right now.

Just found my solution.
In case anybody wonders
    const transformData = r.pipe(
        r.groupBy(r.prop('fooId')),
        r.map((items) => {
            const { fooId, prop, prop2 } = items[0];

            const bars = r.map(item => ({
                barId: item.barId,
                prop: item.prop_1,
                prop2: item.prop2_1
            }), items);

            return { fooId, prop, prop2, bars };
        }),
        r.values
    );


look like fooId, prop, porp2 is group condition. Maybe can modify like this r.groupBy(r.props(['fooId','prop','prop2']))

Would that be more efficient? It would work.

Just prevent same fooId has different prop and prop2

Oh okay. Cant happen though in this case bars are joined on foos and have a n:1 relationship
